# HtmlAgilityPack to replacechild ,why it does not work?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I implement a feature to  request "http://cnblogs.com" page.
When I use HtmlAgilityPack to replace more HtmlNode, but had some occur confuse things-----It can not replace.

The code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;//I Use NuGet to include HtmlAgilityPack(Vs2012)

namespace CatchWebSample
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            string content = wc.DownloadString("http://cnblogs.com");
            document.LoadHtml(content);
            string oldContent = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

            //here, I want to replace all xpath= //div[@class='post_item_foot'] htmlnodes
            HtmlNodeCollection targetNodeCollection = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(@"//div[@class='post_item_foot']");

            HtmlNode newHtmlNode;
            if (targetNodeCollection != null && targetNodeCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < targetNodeCollection.Count; i++)
                {
                    var targetNode = targetNodeCollection[i];
                    newHtmlNode = document.CreateElement("span");
                    newHtmlNode.InnerHtml = HtmlDocument.HtmlEncode("###### REPLACED CONTENT #########");

                    targetNode.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newHtmlNode, targetNode);
                }

                content = document.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;

                //but the result is same of the original data,why it can not replace ?
                bool flag = string.Compare(oldContent, content) == 0;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm so confuse, and why?

Comment: Your code is missing a `}` to mark the end of the foreach...

Comment: yes,i know,but i found it's hard to edit.my English is so so,that i try to edit again,it can not save.

Comment: I edited the code sample you posted, is this what it should look like?

Comment: Is your htmlagilitypack lower than version 4.5?

Comment: It works fine for me. Make sure you're running of the latest version.

Comment: thank you very much,by the way,can you help me for this question?

Comment: @Kuzgun I use NuGet to include this dll,I check it---the version is v4.0.30319,is it this issue?

Comment: I tried it with the latest NuGet version and it's indeed failing.

Comment: @Simon Mourier  can you tell me where to download the latest version?

Comment: Using 1.4.6.0 on .NET Framework v4.0.30319 (4.5)

Comment: @jessehouwing  yes,my dll version is 1.4.6.0, and .netframwork is 4.5,

Comment: If it doesn't work, maybe your sample is incorrect. Please post a working sample somewhere so we can investigate.

Comment: Updated with the test code I used which fails (while I'd swear it shouldn't).

Comment: @SimonMourier  I'm no  familiar with stackoverflow.com,can you tell me how to upload the sample?

Comment: Hi all, I don't know where to upload my sample,now I edit my code again,everyone can copy & test!

Comment: @SimonMourier  can you copy my code to test again?i parse my code again,you can look it now.

Comment: @jessehouwing  Ignore my code，if let you to do this feature,how can you coding with HtmlAgilityPack?

Answer (score 2):

replaceChild() , insertAfter() suddeny   both of them  stopped working for me too.

my best alternative was to replacing innerhtml with "new html string"

```
targetnode.innerhtml = newNodeAsString;
```

**edit:**

there was a bug at *HtmlAgilityPack* inserting values/nodes. due to some caching to make it work faster.

thats why i ditched it. and used **AngleSharp**.

**edit:**

at mid 2017 *HAP* is being developed [here](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack). i won't go back . also you cant create issue at HAP.